# Bash script: write string to file without any output to the terminal, using pipe

Tags: bash, file, sed, pipe

Sorry for the title, i couldn't find proper words to explain my problem.

Here's the code:

```sh
wlan_c=$(iwconfig | sed '/^\(w.*$\)/!d;s/ .*//' > ./wifi_iface)
wlan=$(<./wifi_iface)
echo "$wlan"
```

I get the following output:

```
lo no wireless extensions.
enp4s0 no wireless extensions.
wlp2s0
```

The last line is the result of execution the `echo "$wlan"`.
The previous lines coming from the `iwconfig`, those that are not getting formatted by `sed`.
And the file `./wifi_iface` also has the info i need.
Everything works as intended.

So i really want to get rid of that unwanted output before the `wlp2s0` line.
How do i manage to do this?

Comment: `iwconfig` is probably writing them to `stderr`. The pipe only captures `stdout`.

Comment: No, i'm pretty sure it's `stdout` because it's already getting formatted by `sed` properly. Actually the execution of the `$wlan_c` line in the terminal gives me the result i want: no unwanted output, the correct info is getting written to `./wifi_iface`. But in the script, i get trash output before that.

Comment: Nevermind, i was wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That output must be going to `stderr` rather than `stdout`. Redirect it to `/dev/null`

```
iwconfig 2>/dev/null | sed '/^\(w.*$\)/!d;s/ .*//' > ./wifi_iface
```

There's no need to assign this to `wlan_c`. Since you're writing to the file, nothing will be written to `stdout`, so the assignment will always be empty.